# Grab a specific item in Json data using Python

Tags: python, json, api

I'm currently writing a script to find emails based on the domain name using Hunter.io API

The thing is that my script returns me a JSON with a lot's a details and I only want the mail address in it.

Here's my code :

```
 """script to find emails based on the domain name using Hunter.io"""

import requests # To make get and post requests to APIs
import json # To deal with json responses to APIs
from pprint import pprint # To pretty print json info in a more readable format
from pyhunter import PyHunter # Using the hunter module

# Global variables

hunter_api_key = "API KEY" # API KEY 
contacts = [] # list where we'll store our contacts
contact_info = {} # dictionary where we'll store each contact information
limit = 1 # Limit of emails adresses pulled by the request
value = "value" # <- seems to be the key in Hunter's API of the email adress founded

# TODO: Section A - Ask Hunter to find emails based on the domain name

def get_email_from_hunter(domain_name,limit):
      
    url = "https://api.hunter.io/v2/domain-search"

    params = {
        "domain" : domain_name,
        "limit" : 1,
        "api_key" : hunter_api_key,
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params= params,)

    json_data = response.json()

    email_adress = json_data["data"]["emails"] # <- I have to find witch is the good key in order to return only the mail adress
    #pprint(email_adress)

    contact_info["email_adress"] = email_adress
    contact_info["domain_name"] = domain_name
    pprint(contact_info)
    return contact_info

get_email_from_hunter("intercom.io","1")
```

and here's the JSON returned :

[JSON exemple extracted from the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYXR2.png)

Thanks per advance for the help provided :)

Comment: Have a look at glom (https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which makes it simple to get only the fields you want. Your data/email field returns a list, so you need to parse any element of the list.

Comment: Many thanks I'm checking this out and I'll get back to you

Enjoy your day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
email_addresses = [item['value'] for item in json_data["data"]["emails"]]
```

note, not tested as you post image, not json data as text.